# android searchview actionbar(onQueryTextListner)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

App crashes while implementing onQueryTextListner in searchview in onCreateOptionsMenu . A quick solution would be appreciated :) . I am trying to filter a custom listview !! App crashes while i undo the comment section in onCreateOptions menu.Logcat,java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
                                                  atcom.example.recker.cust_list_filter.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:65).menu.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    />
</menu>


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] names={"Google","Microsoft","Facebook","Amazon","Cisco","Uber","Ola","Samsung","Verizon","Flipkart"};
int[] images={R.drawable.go1_img,R.drawable.mic1_img,R.drawable.fb1_img,R.drawable.ama1_img,R.drawable.cisc1_img,R.drawable.ube1_img,
        R.drawable.ola1_img,R.drawable.sam1_img,R.drawable.ver1_img,R.drawable.flip1_img};
ArrayList<Company> companies=new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
SearchView sv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        Company company=new Company(names[i],images[i]);
        companies.add(company);
    }
     myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,companies);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    sv=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchview1);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_plzz,menu);
    MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
    /*searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            //myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });*/

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

Comment: add your menu.xml file with question

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: nullpointerexception

Comment: but it should not be.... i have tried several ways, when i implement the searchview in the activity below the actionbar, it works fine ! .Its showing a nullpointerexception from the very statement setOnQueryTextListner !